# Datatable sort plugin for day month year hour:minute

Tags: datatables

Is there a sort plugin for the date format

```
16 Jul 2014, 2:04 p.m.
18 Jul 2014, 11:54 a.m.
27 Jun 2014, 5:56 p.m.
```

The dates are currently sorted in the default format (16 Jul should be before 18 Jul but after 27 Jun).

This is my table definition:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dt = $("#files_table").dataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "defaultContent": "No Data",
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 7, ]},
        { "sClass": "center", "aTargets": [ 7, ]},
        { "sType": "date-uk", "aTargets": [ 0, ]},
        ]
});
```

At the bottom where I specify the date type (current "date-uk"), none of the date formats at
http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/ correspond to day name-of-month year hh:mm.

Is my only alternative to make my own data source sort function? It seems like quite a common format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your dates without any additional plugin, only you have to put the timestamp of the date in `data-order` attribute.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/MWalid/pen/yDEsF).

[Documentation](http://datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data#HTML-5).